# Spring serve static resources, doc files can find, but images can't

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I encounter a weird problem as title. Here is my static resources configuration.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/files/**" location="#{'file:' + filePathDefinition.getFileServerDirectory()}" />
```

where second line location value will render like `file:/mnt/upload`.

Files in `/mnt/upload`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 kuen-honglin  wheel     192 Apr 10 16:59 .
drwxrwxr-x  5 kuen-honglin  wheel     160 Apr  9 15:28 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 kuen-honglin  wheel  634119 Apr 10 15:18 2.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 kuen-honglin  wheel       5 Apr  9 15:28 a.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 kuen-honglin  staff    7732 Apr  9 15:29 temp.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  6 kuen-honglin  wheel     192 Apr 10 11:22 twfcc
```

When I visited `http://localhost:8080/gs_web/files/a.txt` or `http://localhost:8080/gs_web/files/temp.pdf`, it worked fine. But if I visited `http://localhost:8080/gs_web/files/2.png`, i got a 404 error.

**Another test:**

I put doc files in `webapp/resources` folder, it worked.

Does anyone has idea about this problem?

Comment: Did you try with different png file? For example something that has a name starting with a letter

Comment: Did you try to rebuild project??? how do you start your application ??

Comment: I just tried immediately, same result.

Comment: @borino I work on eclipse, I clean up tomcat but not works.

Comment: Try changing the group of 2.png from "wheel" to "staff"

Answer (score 0):

I found I did a stupid thing. When I opened spring debug log, it showed that it dispatched to jawr handler. And my jawr config like below:

```
sr = sc.addServlet("BinaryServlet", "net.jawr.web.servlet.JawrServlet");
sr.setInitParameter("configLocation", "/jawr.properties");
sr.setInitParameter("type", JawrConstant.BINARY_TYPE);
sr.addMapping("*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.woff", "*.woff2", "*.ttf", "*.svg", "*.eot");
sr.setLoadOnStartup(0);
```

So all the image files are dispatched to jawr handler.

Thanks all of you great suggestions :)